# Caching data in one Singleton class and using in another in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, oop

I have a class which calls two singleton classes FirstClass and SecondClass as below. Is there a way to access the data computed in FirstClass in the SecondClass. In this case I don't want to make external service call in second class since the first class has already called it. Instead, just use the data (stored in first class function) in the second data function. What are the ways to do it in Spring Framework?

```
public class CallingFunction() {
    List<String> generateData() {
    return Lists.newArrayList(new FirstClass(), new SecondClass())
}

@Singleton
public class FirstClass() extends interface {
    public String function() { 
    //operations. This function calls multiple services and stores ouput  to hashMap
    Map<String, String> hashedData = Maps.newHashMap();
    hashedData.put(dataFromAnotherService);
    return hashedData.get("abc");
    }
}

@Singleton
public class SecondClass() extends interface {
    public String function() { 
    //Use hashedData here instead of invoking the service again.
    //Other operations
    return "data";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a reference of `FirstClass` to `SecondClass`, either by having Spring do it for you (which is an I.o.C. container is for) or do it explicitly in `generateData`.